# Can't retrieve data from database using SOAP web service in java with WSDL (IBM Websphere server)?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I created a webservice which is fetching data from db2 database, It is working fine in my local system but when i deploy the war file in IBM websphere and then access that webservice using wsdl,iam not getting desired output,that means after deploying in websphere iam loosing the database connectivity why is that?
Why iam not getting database connectivity after deploying it in ibm websphere.
This is my code snippet:-

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "javasamples.two.Users")

public class UsersImpl implements Users {

public int getUserCount() { 

    int numusers = 0;
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:db2://localhost:8080/db2";
    String dbClass = "com.db2.jdbc.Driver";
    String query = "Select count(*) FROM user";
    String userName = "root", password = "admin";
    try {

    Class.forName("com.db2.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl, userName, password);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        numusers = rs.getInt(1);
        } //end while
        con.close();
    } //end try

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {

        return numusers;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There is way too little information to be even able to answer this question.

Comment: Added my code snippet please check now

Comment: I doubt that web sphere has `jdbc:db2://localhost:8080/db2` as the location for the database. Also 8080? That generally is the port for the servlet container NOT the database.